# ProgrammingError: column "column" of relation "schema" does not exist

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I'm following this tutorial about using Scrapy with Postgres http://newcoder.io/scrape.  I'm new with postgres and very familiar with scrapy.

Nowhere in the tutorial does it state anything about migrations so I think it intends to generate the tables using `DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)` or within the contents of the code somewhere.

my `models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

import settings


DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()


def db_connect():
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))

def create_scores_table(engine):
    """"""
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

class Scores(DeclarativeBase):
        __tablename__ = "scores"

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        score = Column('score', String, nullable=True)
```

my `pipelines.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Scores, db_connect, create_scores_table

class RrsportsPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):

    engine = db_connect()
    create_scores_table(engine)
    self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def process_item(self, item, spider):
    session = self.Session()
    scores = Scores(**item)
    try:
        session.add(scores)
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
    return item
```

I know the database is connecting correctly too with correct creds and database name.

the full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/rgsports/rgsports/rgsports/pipelines.py", line 44, in process_item
    session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 801, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 392, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 372, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2019, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2137, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2101, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 373, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 532, in execute
    uow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 174, in save_obj
    mapper, table, insert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 800, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "score" of relation "scores" does not exist

LINE 1: INSERT INTO scores (score)
                               ^
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO scores (score) VALUES (%(score)s) RETURNING scores.id'] [parameters: {'score': u'114'}]
```

but when I run the spider:

`ProgrammingError: column "score" of relation "scores" does not exist`

Should I just create the table manually? If so, how? I'd prefer to have it within the code though. Is there something in my models that I'm missing? Or do I have to run models as some sort of deliberate migration?  I can't seem to trigger the tables to be built.

Comment: ok, can you provide the full traceback error?

Comment: Thanks, I just did.

Comment: from what I see your code matches the tutorial format. have you tried copy and pasting the example given in the tutorial to see if it runs correctly

Comment: Nope, I will try that tomorrow. Good suggestion. I'll go back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

In pipeline.py it looks like you need to import create_scores_table instead of create_matchups_table

it reads:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Scores, db_connect, create_matchups_table
```

should read:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Scores, db_connect, create_scores_table
```

Comment: That was just an error on my part when preparing the question for stackoverflow. Good catch but that's not the issue. I'll edit right now.